# How do I get a Bootstrap 4 nav to appear on the same line as a header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav, bootstrap-4

Here you can see what it looks like right now.

What it looks like now

[image: What it looks like now]

How do I get the nav to appear on the right side of the screen while making it be on the same line as the copyright? I cannot seem to get anything to work that I have seen on here so far.

Here is my current code:

```
<div class="container-fluid footer">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <h5 style="display: inline">Copyright © 2017 Custom Prop Shop</h5>
        <ul class="nav flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-end pull-right">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="request-estimate.html">Request an Estimate</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="our-work.html">Our Work</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="our-clients.html">Our Clients</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="our-story.html">Our Story</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS is only controlling color of the text/background and the font-size for this part.

Comment: where is your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to make the container `d-flex`, and then use `my-auto` to vertically center the `h5`...

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
        <h5 class="my-auto">Copyright © 2017 Custom Prop Shop</h5>
        <ul class="nav flex-column flex-sm-row">..</ul>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/1WWhy3uP9C

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
<div class="container-fluid footer">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h5 style="display: inline">Copyright © 2017 Custom Prop Shop</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <ul class="nav flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-end pull-right">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="request-estimate.html">Request an Estimate</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="our-work.html">Our Work</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="our-clients.html">Our Clients</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="our-story.html">Our Story</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

You can reference Bootstrap Grid Options over here https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options

Answer (score -1):

add `float: left` on the `h5`.

or `float: right` on the `ul`